# Javascript not wanting to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

For some odd reason this image slider does not want to work can anyone point out the problem i have a feeling it is with including the javascript also the  does not want to work also so i went with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/slider.css"></link>
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="includes/js/slider.js"></link>
<link type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></link>
```

or is this the correct way either way it dont seem to work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/slider.css"></link>
<script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="includes/js/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

---

Edit full code:

```
<div class="mask">
<ul class="imgHolder">
   <li>
      <img width="270" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg/270px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg" />
   </li>
   <li>
      <img width="270" src="http://www.mallorcaweb.net/masm/Planetas/Jupiter.jpg" />
   </li>
    <li>
      <img width="270" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/280px-FullMoon2010.jpg" />
   </li>
   <li>
      <img width="270" src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/sun-update-1.jpg" />
   </li>
   <li>
      <img width="270" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Neptune.jpg/240px-Neptune.jpg" />
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul class="thumbHolder">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
<span class="control Bleft">Prev</span>
<span class="control Bright">Right</span>
```

Comment: adding .js with script tag, not link tag, link tag for css, give us your full code, then we can help you pointing the error

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: @arun whow would i do that developers console?

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: press F12 if you are using windows system, other wise it is available under Tools menu

Comment: yea i got that it gave me this error which leads to slider.js on line 21 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' slider.js:21
(anonymous function) heres a link to the tutorial i grabbed it from  jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/308

Comment: that fiddle didnt use slider.js, only jquery with animate

Comment: im not sure what animate is can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/css/slider.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/slider.js"></script>
```

Notice that I have removed the `rel` tag, and I have added leading slashes at the beginning of each path, so that it always loads from the root.

Comment: Nope stil nothing my css has been dislaying do you think maybe i have the wrong version of jquery can that cause it not to work?

Comment: yes it says this: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' and didnt know it did that

Comment: my slider.js i got it from a tutorial here if you want take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/308/ on line 21

Comment: I guess the method 'on' referred here is the alternative of the method 'live'. Although both has almost the same functionality, try changing that method to 'live' and I guess that is what is the problem

Comment: well it got rid of the error but still dont work? should i try and update my jquery library

Comment: no im just going to scrap this one and find another lol i dont have time for errors :)

Comment: Have a look at this page: **http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/03/jquery-slider.html**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the jQuery script before all dependent scripts, i.e. all scripts that use jQuery.

--

Also, link tags are self closing and script tags are used for js files not link tags.

Comment: maybe do i have the wrong jquery library maybe i need an updated one? instead of jquery-1.5.2.min.js?

Answer (score 0):

`Link` tag is used to pointing and adding `css` files inside page where as `script` tag is used to add `client side` script into code example `vbscript` and `javascript` etc.

One more thing you need to **include `jQuery` before any of other `jQuery plugin`** which are depended on `jQuery`.

**Example**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="includes/js/slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok well i had the script tags in there and it seemed not to want to grab my javascript code i have it pointing to the right directory

Comment: still not working do you think i need an updated jquery library?